# Xmonad: Combine dwm-style workspaces per physical screen with cycling function

Tags: haskell, xmonad, multiple-monitors

my question should be a piece of cake for anyone a bit learned in Haskell:

I would like to use the dwm-like multihead-setup: each physical screen gets it's own set of workspaces. No automatic swapping of windows or focus or whatsoever.
This is provided by the extension XMonad.Layout.IndependentScreens (http://xmonad.org/xmonad-docs/xmonad-contrib/XMonad-Layout-IndependentScreens.html) which works fine.

But I would equally like to use the cycling function provided by XMonad.Actions.CycleWS (http://xmonad.org/xmonad-docs/xmonad-contrib/XMonad-Actions-CycleWS.html) which works equally fine (by itself).

As it is, when I cycle through the workspaces, it goes: Screen1 WS1 <--> Screen2 WS1 <--> Screen1 WS2 <--> Screen2 WS2 etc.

The cycling function would have to be wrapped in a independent-layout-function i guess. As I said, this is probably extremely simple, but I know little of Haskell and couldn't figure it out.

Both of the extensions are well documented, so this should be a simple one for some of you guys.

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the main trick is to build a `WSType` which informs CycleWS that you're only interested in physical workspaces that appear on the same screen as the current physical workspace. Here's how you would do that.

```
isOnScreen :: ScreenId -> WindowSpace -> Bool
isOnScreen s ws = s == unmarshallS (tag ws)

currentScreen :: X ScreenId
currentScreen = gets (screen . current . windowset)

spacesOnCurrentScreen :: WSType
spacesOnCurrentScreen = WSIs (isOnScreen <$> currentScreen)
```

Then you can use `spacesOnCurrentScreen` in keybindings something like this:

```
, ((modM, xK_whatever ), moveTo  Next spacesOnCurrentScreen)
, ((modM, xK_whatever2), shiftTo Next spacesOnCurrentScreen)
```

I haven't tested it, but it typechecks at least. ;-)

Comment: Hi Daniel, thanks a lot! this looks promising. For now, he gives me "not in scope"-errors for tag, screen, current, <$>. Is this maybe due to a module that I didn't load?

Comment: @mat Perhaps. `tag`, `screen`, and `current` come from `XMonad.StackSet` (some people import this qualified as `W`, so perhaps `W.tag`, etc. will work for you), and `(<$>)` can be replaced with `\`fmap\`` without importing anything or can be imported from `Control.Applicative`.

Comment: Yes, this looks good. I don't have time for testing right now, maybe this evening. But it seems to work. Ill report back.

Comment: Actually, I just tested it anyway -- it works! I used the "W."-qualification and imported `Control.Applicative` (fmap didn't work, but that doesn't matter). Can you post your comment as an answer so I can accept it? -- Thanks a lot!

Comment: Damn, I'm tired, you posted it as an answer... :-) Sorry